# Solr - Passing custom parameter for fetch query in Data Import

Tags: php, search, solr, full-text-search, solr4

I have configured Solr to import data from MySql database. I need to pass a parameter ( say user_id ) and what I need to gain out of this is to import only the record that matches the passed user id.

`http://googlieye:8983/solr/db/dataimport?command=full-import&
entity=user_data_import&user_id=431269`

Is it possible to get this done? I'm still trying to work this out. Any kind of suggestion or idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the query params and then read them in data-config.xml like this:

```
select * from users where user_id=${dataimporter.request.entity}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but didn't give me any positive feedback. The fetch count and processed count values were zero ( although there weren't any errors, where the status are becomes red. It was green in Solr UI ).

Anything I'm missing mate? could you point out things that I may have missed or I should look for. Appreciate it.

Comment: You've asked how to pass an url parameter to data importer. I've answered that. Why the processed count is zero I don't know, might be a million of reasons. Did you debug your queries to see what they return?